# Error when creating Synonym in SQL Server 2005 with the same table name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, synonym

I want to create Synonym for a table , so all the other users in this database use this Synonym  instead of writing   **databasename.schema.table** , but when I write :

```
CREATE SYNONYM [ACCT_STMT] FOR [AccountStatementPRD].[dbo].[ACCT_STMT]
GO
```

it generates an error msg :

> There is already an object named
>   'ACCT_STMT' in the database. Msg 4606,

in oracle , I can create Synonym  with the same table name !

Comment: You **cannot** create a synonym by the same name in the same database in SQL Server. You *can* create a synonym in a different database - but not in the same one. The object names in a SQL Server database have to be unique across all object types - i.e. you couldn't create a procedure or view of that name either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if all you want is to use it by name only, and you already executing the statment in the correct DB, you don't have to use databasename.schema.tablename, just use tablename

for example, instead of

```
SELECT * FROM [AccountStatementPRD].[dbo].[ACCT_STMT]
```

you can just do

```
SELECT * FROM [ACCT_STMT]
```

as far as having the same name for synonym, that will not work in the same `DB`